# Button that functions conditionally depending on whether or not another button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, button, conditional-statements

I'm making a program with 4 players.

Each player having a main button to trigger a main function and 3 more buttons, each blocking one of the 3 remaining players from performing the main function while triggering the same main function for the player pushing the button

When the blocked player pushes their main button it triggers a different function than the main one.

I have been able to make the main button and its functionality but not the effects of the block button.

Currently I'm putting this in my external js script for the blocked function:

```
if (document.getElementById("kelly-block-john").clicked == true){
  document.getElementById("john-button").onclick = "johnBlocked()";
}
```

Does anybody have any idea on how to make the effects of the block buttons work?

Comment: 1. Delegate. Please do not have `kelly-block-john` andd `john-block-kelly` but have generic class or IDs to access from a container click. 2. Have a boolean you can test: `something.addEventListener("click",function() { if (blocked) return; /* here the click works */ })`

Answer (score -2):

Use Event Listener to check if the button is clicked and also to run a function when it is clicked.
Find out the details and syntax here:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Also you only need a few real answers to be able to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) - if you see my comment to the question, it is a more detailed answer than your comment